# Conditional operator not working in React native properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

I'm using a react native and native cli with navigation 5. I have three stacks.

1. AuthStack
2. UserStack
3. AdminStack

I'm using a **react.Context()** to jump from login to other stack. But now the main issue I'm facing is that when I set like this:

```
 { user == false && log==0  ?
   <AuthStackScreen />
     :
   <UserStackScreens /> 
 }
OR
 { user == false && log==0  ?
   <AuthStackScreen />
     :
   <AdminStackScreens /> 
 }
```

it works fine but when I do this:

```
 { user == false && log==0  ?
    <AuthStackScreen />
    :
    <View>
      { superUser == false ? 
         <UserStackScreens /> 
         :
         <AdminStackScreens/>
      }
      </View>
  }
```

After login, it is displaying me a white screen, not a UserStack and Admin STack just white.
Here's the complete code of App.js and login Function from login component:

```
 export const LoginContext = React.createContext();
 
 
 const App = () => {
   const [user, setUser] = useState(false)
   const [superUser, setSuperUser] = useState(false)
   const [log, setLog] = useState(0)
   const [role, setRole] = useState('seller')
   const [f_seller, setF_seller] = useState(false)
   
   console.log('appSuperUser',superUser)
   useEffect(()=>{ 
     getKeysData(dataKeys)
   },[]) 
   const dataKeys = ['token', 'super_user_status', 'isLoggedIn'];    
   const getKeysData = async (keys) => {
     const stores = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
     const aData = await Promise.all(stores.map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value})))
     const token = aData[0]['token']
     const super_user_status = aData[1]['super_user_status']
     const isLoggedIn = aData[2]['isLoggedIn']
       if(isLoggedIn == 1){
         setLog(1)
       }
     
     }

     const Stack = () => {
       return(
         <View>
            { superUser == false ? 
            <BuyerDashboardStackScreens /> 
            :
            <AdminDashboardStackScreens/>
          }
         </View>
       )
     }
   return (
     <NavigationContainer>
          <LoginContext.Provider value={{user,setUser, log, setLog, superUser, setSuperUser}} >
        { user == false && log==0  ?
          <AuthStackScreen />
          :
          <View>
            { superUser == false ? 
            <UserStackScreens /> 
            :
            <AdminStackScreens/>
          }
         </View>
        }
        </LoginContext.Provider> 
      
     </NavigationContainer>
   );
 };
```

**LoginFunc**

```
const login = async () => {
        if (email != '' && password != '') {
            const login_Credentials = new FormData();
            login_Credentials.append('username', email);
            login_Credentials.append('password', password);
            setPress(true)
            await axios({
                method: 'POST',
                url: api + 'login/',
                data: login_Credentials,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
            }).then(async function (response) {
                if (response.data.success == true) {
                    console.log(response.data)
                    const token = response.data.token.toString();
                    const super_user_status = response.data.super_user_status.toString();
                    const isLoggedIn = "1"
                    
                    

                    await AsyncStorage.multiSet([['isLoggedIn',isLoggedIn],['token', token], ['super_user_status', super_user_status]])
                    setUser(true)
                    if (super_user_status == 1){
                        
                        setSuperUser(true)
                    }
                    
                    setEmail('')
                    setPassword('')
                    setPress(false)
                } else if (response.data.success == false) {
                    if(response.data.status===2){
                        const token = response.data.token.toString();
                        await AsyncStorage.multiSet([['token', token]])
                        navigation.navigate('EmailOTP', { email: { email } })
                    }
                    setPress(false)
                    setErrorMsg(response.data.error)
                    setEmail('')
                    setPassword('')
                    
                    
                    
                }
            }).catch(function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                setErrorMsg('Server Error 404');
                setPress(false)

            })
        } else {
            setErrorMsg('Please Enter Username/Password.')
            setPress(false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe because you wrap stack in a view, try replace view by fragment. <>
      { superUser == false ? 
         <UserStackScreens /> 
         :
         <AdminStackScreens/>
      }
      </>

Comment: i think its a flex issue can you try adding `style={{flex:1}}` to the View wrapping UserStackScreen and AdminStackScreen

Comment: Tangential to your issue, but why are you comparing to false/falsey values to access the happy path (the truthy side) of the ternary operator? It's not very Boolean Zen. The `View` component *might* be the issue, but easier to confirm/rule it out if you could provide a running [Expo snack](https://expo.io/) that reproduces this issue that we can inspect and live debug.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it on expo and it's working fine for me: https://snack.expo.io/6NAskxpAD

One possible scenario could be that your View import is somehow incorrect. Please check that once because when I tried to reproduce this in ReactJS and did not import "View", it gave me white screen as well.

P.S. This is React Native and not ReactJS, right? If this is ReactJS, missing import of View seems to be the issue.